# Background image with opacity

Tags: css, background-image, opacity

I've been trying to display a navigation bar in front of a full screen size background image which I want to adjust it's opacity. I am able to display the nav bar and the image correctly until I modify the image's opacity. When I do that, the background image is not displayed full size. The image is only displayed until the navigation bar starts

```
html {
    background-image:url(../img/sea.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.navigation {
        background-color: grey;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        top:300px;
        width: 100%;

}

.navigation li{
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:110px;
}

.navigation a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: setting `opacity:0.5;` on the html element is probably not a good idea. Generally setting `opacity` to anything other than 1 in order to change background opacity on any element that has some content is not a good idea.

Comment: What is the purpose of having the main background image of the whole page have opacity in the first place? Unless you have also set a background-color for the html element (which I see nothing of in your example) – what exactly are you expecting to see “shine through” via that opacity? I guess your best options are to either make that background image a PNG with alpha transparency already included, or use another element that spans the whole viewport, positioned behind the actual page content, and give that the background image and opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity applies to your entire element, not only your background. So by doing

```css
html {
    background-image:url(../img/sea.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

You are telling your entire document (`html`) to have a 50% opacity.

So if you're trying to have a background with opacity of 50% two options:

#### option 1

Your background is fixed and will only be 50% opacity, all the time: I recommend to modify the image itself to be a 50% opacity image (via any image editor) and save it as `png` which will preserve opacity. 
This however is good only if 2 conditions are matched:

1. Your background opacity will never change
2. Your image is fairly small ( a `png` is significantly bigger than a `jpg`  for example, and so if you want your page load to be reasonnable, keep it small using a [repeatable image](http://subtlepatterns.com/) for example).

#### option 2 (what you want I think)

Your background opacity needs to change for any reason, or is too big in `png` and you want to keep it as a `jpg` or whatever your format is: add a `div` containing your background and only your background, and change its opacity like below.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%; /* or whatever your desired height is */
  height: 100%; /* or whatever your desired height is */
  min-width: 100%; /* or whatever your desired width is */
  width: 100%; /* or whatever your desired width is */
}

#background {
  background-image:url(../img/sea.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0; /* To make sur it's below the rest */
}
```

And your html should be something like that:

```html
 <html>
   <div id="background"></div>
   ... All your other html goes here ...
 </html>
```

Comment: I'd suggest `z-index:-1`, but I'm superstitious. In any case: Please keep in mind that using `opacity` and `z-index` can lead to [unexpected results](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) if you don't pay enough attention.